# How to imitate a loop inside mongodb aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a documents in my db like this:

```
{
  _id: "",
  "name":"myname",
  category: "abc",
  category1: "abc1"
}
{
  _id: ""
  "name":"myname",
  category: "bcd",
  category1: "bcd1",
  category2: "bcd2"
}
```

Where the category fields can go upto any number it is not predefined but if `category2` is present `category1` is also there for sure.
The hierarchy is like

```
category -> category1 -> category2 -> ......
```

Now I if I want to do a `search` where I match the `given text` with all categories of a document without knowing the number category present I would need something like a `loop`.

```
db.collection('collection', aggregate([
  $match: {
    "category": 'text',
    "category1": 'text',
     .
     .
     so on 
  }
]));
```

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Why not an array of categories?

Comment: @Joe I am thinking of proceeding by making an array of categories but after that not sure how to implement match on them? can you help with that?

Comment: this is poor schema design. you should make categories an array of strings like `{categories:["abc","bcd","xyz"]}`. this way you can create an index for the `categories` field which would enable efficient queries and avoid collection scans. if you need to maintain the order of categories, make them an array of objects like `[{id:1,name:"abc"},{id:2,name:bcd}]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the total # of categories is bounded, write one condition per category joined with $or. It might be laborious but it should work.

Comment: Can you please give an example on this, I did not understand